# C Programming linux , read system inputs like ping or ls -l

Tags: c, linux, system

i trying make a custom method what causes return a char with system output.

the pseudocode like this.

```
char *my_Out(char *in ){
    in = system ("ping %s",in);
    return in;
}
```

thanks for the help.

Comment: If you'd included `<stdlib.h>` (which declares `system()`), you would have known that it returns an integer and not a `char *`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `popen`, which returns you a stream that you can read the output from. By reading until end-of-file, into a string (probably one that dynamically grows as necessary), you can implement what you're asking for.

Comment: Though if you're looking for one of the pieces of information contained in an `ls -l`, say, you can probably get it a lot more easily with a library function (`stat`).

Comment: @Jefromi: +1 for your insight, although a small nit: `stat` is usually a system call, not a library function. :-P

Comment: Chris: `stat` is usually a library function *wrapping* a system call (he who lives by the nit...)

Comment: @caf: These days, yes (because of different `struct stat` layouts between kernel versions, and the need to keep user code binary-compatible). Originally, no, it was a straight system call. Nonetheless, good call. +1

Answer (score 2):

A few things

1. `system()` is not a printf style function.  You'll need to use `sprintf()` to create your argument before.
2. `system()`'s return value is an int, non a char
3. It's generally not a good idea to overwrite function parameters.

What are you trying to do?  It looks like all this function does is run `ping` (which, without the -c argument, will never finish running on linux).

Comment: I disagree with point 3.  While it may be unusual and break your style, there is nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Duplicate the stdout to some other file descriptor by using dup2.After the execution of the command read all the lines from the file using that file descriptor and return it.
```